# Xamarin Android Player Start Up Issues

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I worked on Xamarin.Forms application and I used Xamarin Android Player for preview android application in this platform. It's worked well and so faster than google android emulator.

Suddenly, It was not working properly in my mac machine and trigger the error as follows[image]

I uninstalled the player and try again but getting the same issues again and again.

If anyone facing the same issues like this, Please help me out in this to run back the player well.

Comment: maybe uninstall Oracle VM Virtual Box and reinstall or reset the device you are trying to launch back to factory

Comment: Please generate Bug Report and put it in post

Comment: You can always use Genymotion emulator which is way faster then both Microsoft and Google emulators